# How can I simulate usb connection between two virtual machines with qemu?

Tags: usb, qemu

I need usb connection between VMs such as host to host communication. But i have no idea to set it up with Qemu. Do you have any clues?

Comment: This is way too broad a question to be reasonbly answered here. Can you be much more specific as to exactly where you are having trouble based on your research of how to do this?

Comment: I am so sorry for too short and simple question. I have a situation two VMs must have different networks and must not have tcp/ip connection between two VMs. So we are trying to communicate data via USB. I developed an application which can communicate via usb host to host cable in physical environment. But my aim is to establish connection between virtual machines without physical host to host cable.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe in more detail what you need. "My client doesn't allow IP based connection between VMs" is a very odd condition, as is "I need host-to-host communication by USB". What is your actual use case? For what do you need the communicaton? Why is IP disallowed? Does it have to be USB host-to-host, or could you maybe communicate via PPP over a serial port? Etc.

Comment: And I very much would like to see your application that allows Linux to communicate via USB host-to-host, because I've not seen this working on real hardware, yet.

Comment: Okay. I am running twe VMs which have different networks. One is normal internet connection and other one is internal private network. These VMs must not have IP connection between them because of security. We call it 'Network saperation'. And I am trying to use barrier(https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) for them. I made an application which can transfer ip packet to usb because barrier needs ip connection. If barrier send packet to localhost, the application receives it and transfer to usb. Other side receives usb data and transfer to localhost then barrier recognize it.

Comment: I tested it successfully in physical environment with usb host to host cable. but i don't want to use host to host cable in Virtual environment. So that is why i want to know how to simulate usb host to host connection between VMs.

Comment: What kind of "usb host to host cable"? there's no usb standard way to communicate host to host. There are some host-to-host usb cables (which are not just cables, but active components which simulate eg. 2 usb->serial adapters connected to each other) -- if you really have such a cable, then plug its both ends into the guest, and then use USB pass-through in qemu to let the 1st vm use one end, and the 2nd vm the other.

Comment: Please make amendments by editing the question.

Comment: This looks like a massive miss-understanding of Network separation: Using a different type of network will break network separation (A network is a network). Connecting two nodes with a network does not always break network separation. e.g. the RAM is connected to the CPU. Two nodes in the same room are connected. Two virtual nodes in the same host are connected (this just inter-process communication).

Comment: Passing inter-process communication through a physical USB host-to-host. is a security and reliability problem waiting to happen. A usb host-to-host is as @mosvy says 2 serial adaptors back to back (so an inter-process pipe) or two network adaptors back to back (so an internal network connection).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any VM host which simulates USB connections between VMs, but you can use [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net) for an USB connection over IP (which will work between VMs), or, depending on what you want to do, you can create "virtual" USB root devices on a single VM, and run different processes for the host and client (gadget) side.

Note that USB is asymmetric, normally has a single host with many clients, and both `usbip` and a virtual USB root only simulate this normal mode of operation (AFAIK).

USB-C host-to-host alternate mode is very new, and not even all drivers for real hardware support that, and though I heard that newer versions of Linux can do it, I've never seen a working instance myself

Comment: i must not have ip based connection between virtual machines. My client doesn't allow it. According to you, using gadget is maybe a way i can try. but still i don't know how to make communication between two gadgets.